# webpack angularjs es6 image path

Tags: angularjs, html, image, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I create on my view a tag img with src; but the image don't show. 
What is the path? 
Thanks All
Samu

my test.html

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <img src='img/logo.png'></img>
    <h1> TEST
    </h1>

</div>4
```

My structure is:

x:\src\pages\test\test.html

x:\src\pages\test\img\logo.png

webpack.config.js

```
 }, {
    // ASSET LOADER
    // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader
    // Copy png, jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, woff, woff2, ttf, eot files to output
    // Rename the file using the asset hash
    // Pass along the updated reference to your code
    // 
  test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
  loader: 'file'
}, {
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's your html loader.

Try to change it from raw-loader to html-loader :

```
{ 
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'html'
}
```

https://github.com/webpack/html-loader